# Is there any benefit of combining several unicast into a single multicast?

Tags: ip

If a node has to send the same data to multiple nodes, it is obvious that multicasting the data would improve bandwidth usage. However, if a node has to send different data to different nodes, would there be any benefit in combining these data into one large data and multicasting it? It is obvious that recipients would receive unnecessary data, and I also think bandwidth utilization would increase compared to unicasting the different data to intended recipients. Can there be some benefit if the size of unicast data is small?

Answer (score 1):

> if a node has to send different data to different nodes, would there be any benefit in combining these data into one large data and multicasting it?

No. That only increases complexity (data distribution, multiplexing) and wastes bandwidth without any benefit - the combined data needs to be sent in any case.

Comment: unless of course the medium is actually broadcast, then all the bets are off

Comment: @Effie With a purely broadcast medium, the efficiency is the same but there's no benefit either. However, you're making a good point of CSMA in your answer - more generally, if the cost of *packet processing* (including bus arbitration) outweighs the *bandwidth* disadvantage (which may be small to non-existent), then there's a benefit overall. However, such a network has got a severe design problem to start with. ;-)

Comment: yeah, wireless networks have a severe design problem: designing them is super hard :D

Answer (score 1):

Neither is obvious and everything depends on network topology, actual properties of layer 2, 3, and 4, traffic pattern, exact problem statement, and other stuff. You can't give a universal answer for all cases. You have to consider exact problem and derive the solution for the exact problem.

**One one hand:**

> If a node has to send the same data to multiple nodes, it is obvious that multicasting the data would improve bandwidth usage.

if the paths are completely disjoined than the bandwidth usage would not improve.

Managing multicast may cause more overhead if the number of recepients is small.

There are also a separate set of issues if multicast needs to be reliable. Reliable multicast transport protocols are generally more complicated than reliable unicast TCP.

*[something to think about]* A really interesting reliable multicast problem: sender sends a multicast packet. Then sender expects (unicast) acknowledgements. Some subset of receivers did not receive the packet (got lost or had transmission errors). There are no ACKs and sender needs to retransmit the packet. What does the sender do: multicast or unicast to specific receivers?

**On the other hand:**

> However, if a node has to send different data to different nodes, would there be any benefit in combining these data into one large data and multicasting it?

What does the network look like? More precicely what do links look like.

On a broadcast link, you cannot unicast to begin with.

On a contention broadcast link (anything with carrier sensing), sending one big block may be better than sending a lot of small ones.

Again, sending data reliably vs unreliably will make a pretty big difference.

> I also think bandwidth utilization would increase compared to unicasting the different data to intended recipients.

This would be a problem is a) there is not enough bandwidth and b) not sending or receiving data is cheaper than sending data (e.g., energy efficiency).

*[something to think about]* Worst case scenario is a wireless link. It is contention and semi-broadcast[*]. On the other hand actively sending and receiving data is power hungry and should be avoided as much as possible (you want the radio units to "sleep" as much as possible). I don't see how one can answer this question.

[*] when I leaned wireless networks we used the term semi-broadcast which described the following properties. Wireless medium is somewhat similar to CSMA. Wireless singal propagates on a certain range around the sender. In a sense it is broadcast, because everybody in the range of the sender hear the signal and sending another signal in this range will destroy the signal. But it is not like a wire broadcast (e.g., CSMA/CD Ethernet), because sender range does not necessary cover all the devices sharing the medium (L2 segment?). So it is kinda broadcast but on a limited range.

Comment: Semi-broadcast?

Comment: @RonTrunk hm, this is not a commonly accepted term... /away looking for a better one